# Calling an XAgent from a traditional Domino web app via AJAX

Tags: xpages

I have an XAgent I have created that works just fine via `window.location` but I can't get it to work via AJAX. This agent is called from a delete button on a popup div, so rather than writing to my responseStream in my XAgent, I'd prefer to just run my agent and close my popup via javascript when it is finished.

My XAgent is called by the URL `doc.$DBPath.value + "/xAgent_DeleteDemand.xsp?open&id=" + doc.$DocUNID.value` and looks like this:

```
javascript:importPackage(foo);
try {
    var url:java.lang.String = context.getUrl().toString();
    print(url);
    if (param.containsKey("id")) {
        var unid = param.get("id");
    } else {
        throw "No unid given";
    }
    XAgent.deleteDemand(unid);
} catch (e) {
    print(e);
}
```

My actual code is in the `foo` package but that doesn't seem relevant because I'm not even getting my URL printed. I can say the the URL being generated and called works just fine using `window.location` so it is safe to assume that the problem is elsewhere.

I have a sneaking suspicion that maybe context doesn't have any meaning when called via AJAX from a non XPage app, but I don't know for sure.

I don't think there is anything special about my AJAX code but here it is just in case. It has been working fine for a long time.

```
function createAJAXRequest(retrievalURL, responseFunction) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        AJAXReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        AJAXReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    showHideIndicator("block")
    var currentTime = new Date()
    AJAXReq.open("GET", retrievalURL + "&z=" + currentTime.getTime());
    AJAXReq.onreadystatechange = eval(responseFunction);
    AJAXReq.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the immediate problem would be, but as some troubleshooting steps:

- The resultant URL is just server-relative and not on a different server+protocol combination, right?
- Do you see anything on the browser's debug console when clicking the button?
- Is there an entry in the browser's debug Network panel for the request at all?

Comment: URL is all in the same application so that isn't an issue. Nothing on the browser debug console at all. Nothing in the Network panel. It looks like I'm getting a Type mismatch on the line `AJAXReq.onreadystatechange = eval(responseFunction)`, but responseFunction contains `closePopup('Frame_Container')` and if I just fire the event in the console it works just fine. I'm off to google `onreadystatechange` to see if there is something I don't know about it.

Comment: I have the agent firing successfully. It looks like the AJAX function wasn't robust enough. There is still a problem trying to close the popup after, but that is a purely JS issue. Thanks.